# Episode where Picard confronts admiral who court-martialed him

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

In the episode Captain Picard is sitting in Ten-Forward when another officer, now an admiral, approaches him. They come to quarrel over an incident in the past, the admiral says something about a court martial being "standard procedure when a ship is lost".

Comment: Again we see how Star Trek is "Hornblower in space"; court martial was standard procedure for a ship being lost in the age of sail as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is **[TNG: Measure of a Man](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Measure_Of_A_Man_(episode))**

> **PICARD:** *Oh, you did more than your job. You enjoyed it.*
>
> **PHILLIPA:** *Not true! A court martial is standard procedure when a ship is lost. I was doing my duty as an officer of the Judge Advocate
> General.*
>
> [TNG: Measure of a Man](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/135.htm)

For the record, [Phillipa Louvois](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Phillipa_Louvois) isn't an *Admiral* but she has been promoted from Lt Cmdr to Captain since he last saw her (when she was prosecuting him for losing the Stargazer)

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: @Nu'Daq - On the plus side, your quote was spot on.

Comment: also the episode in which we find Picard may have a history of domestic violence ;)

Comment: ... which does make me wonder why a simple Google didn't do the trick *ahem*

Comment: @BoundaryImposition - SE policy is that we should "embrace non-Googlers" :-)

Comment: @Valorum: Actually, SE policy is that people asking questions should perform prior research rather than expecting us to do _all_ the work. :)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition - Sure, but some people are very poor at using Google ;-) I do agree that any question that can be answered by googling the title is almost certainly worthy of a downvote.

Comment: @Valorum: Exactly. Hopefully then they will be encouraged to _learn_ that basic skill, for the good of us all :)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I have often googled something to be brought here (looking for an answer) only to see comments telling people to Google it...

Comment: @user001: More than one result is usually shown for a Google search. In this case, the second result for `"standard procedure when a ship is lost"` is the answer, so there's not really any excuse!

Answer (score 4):

In [Measure of a Man](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Measure_Of_A_Man_(episode)) Picard confronts [Phillipa Louvois](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Phillipa_Louvois) who had been promoted to Captain since she prosecuted his court martial.